# How to dissociate two different compatible conditions in an if else structure

Tags: c

Good morning. I'm  still a beginner with codeblocks, and I was wondering how to dissociate two cases using an `if`...`else` structure combined with a `for` structure.

I'm currently writing a code which checks the cards of a player, and determines if the user has two different cards that fulfill a condition. Each and every cards are different and unique. I was wondering if there's any way to check which p would fulfill the condition in the first if loop so that the second loop would be initialized at `j + i` where `i` would be the value of the `p` fulfilling the first condition, thus preventing the code to check two times the same card. The success would be having 2 cards among the following : 2, 4 , 6. I thought of making a single if loop which would check if the user has card 2 and 4 or 2 and 6 or 4 and 2 or 4 and 6 and so on, but I figured out it would take too much time. 
Here's the code I made

```
if( p >= 2)
{
    for(p=2;p<8;p++ )
    {
        if( Tab[nbjoueur].TBatiment[p]==2 ||Tab[nbjoueur].TBatiment[p]==4 ||
                Tab[nbjoueur].TBatiment[p]==6)
        {
            for(j=2+i;j<8;j++)
            {
                if( Tab[nbjoueur].TBatiment[j]==2 ||Tab[nbjoueur].TBatiment[j]==4 || 
                        Tab[nbjoueur].TBatiment[j]==6 ){
                    printf("\n Victory ");
                    Tab[nbjoueur].etoilevictoire = Tab[nbjoueur].etoilevictoire + 2;}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: First, please "dissociate" Codeblocks which is merely an IDE and C which is a language :)  So Codeblocks is really has no relevance to you question. As for the question it is not very clear what you are trying to do

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to have the 2nd `if` have only 2 conditions instead of 3?

Comment: Well I knew it wouldn't be easy to explain it, basically I want to check if the user has two cards (among a 7 cards limit he can keep) which fulfill a condition in the game. The TBatiment is sorted according to the value of the cards the player wants to keep so the Tab[nbjoueur].TBatiment[p] equals to a card from the player. I want to avoid the code to check two times the same card. I want it to check one card, and if the player has one of the cards needed, the code would check the other cards without checking the card that fulfill the condition once again.

Comment: Ok, if I understand your question, you want to check if the player has one of the winning cards in one single loop?

Comment: So, as clarified, stripped of all the stuff about loops, your goal is to determine whether the array `Tab[nbjoueur].TBatiment` contains at least two of the values 2, 4, 6?

Answer (score 0):

You end up checking the same element in the inner loop that you did in the outer loop if `p` is the same as `j`.  So first check that that is not the case.

```
if( (p != j) && ( Tab[nbjoueur].TBatiment[j]==2 ||
                  Tab[nbjoueur].TBatiment[j]==4 || Tab[nbjoueur].TBatiment[j]==6 ))
```

Alternately, you can start the inner loop at `p + 1`:

```
for(j=p+1;j<8;j++)
```

Comment: @Xenologue Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want to achieve ? :

```
uint8_t nbCarteGagnante = 0;
if( p >= 2)
{
    for(p=2;p<8;p++ )
    {
        if( Tab[nbjoueur].TBatiment[p]==2)
        {
            nbCarteGagnante++;
        }

        if(Tab[nbjoueur].TBatiment[p]==4 )
        {
            nbCarteGagnante++;
        }

        if(Tab[nbjoueur].TBatiment[p]==6)
        {
            nbCarteGagnante++;
        }

        // check victory
        if(nbCarteGagnante >= 2)
        {
            printf("\n Victory ");
            Tab[nbjoueur].etoilevictoire = Tab[nbjoueur].etoilevictoire + 2;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```